# Concatenating ArrayList<Integer> elements into a single string without loop in java

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist

I have an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
al.add(3);
al.add(8);
al.add(123);
al.add(41);
```

Not i want

```
String s="3812341";
```

Can this be done without a loop or by built in methods?

Comment: How do you get the elements without any built-in methods?

Comment: @namenotfound The method `join(CharSequence, CharSequence...)` in the type String is not applicable for the arguments `(String, List<Integer>)`.

Comment: No, it can't be done without built-in methods. You can't get values from the ArrayList without calling a build-in method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, this can be easily solved using Stream API.

```
String s = al.stream().map(String::valueOf).reduce((x, y) -> x + y).get();
```

We build a stream using stream() function and maps the Integer value to String value and finally reduces it to a String using reduce() function. This will return an Optional object which is why we are using get() function at the end to get the real value.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use below code

```
String s = al.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\, ", "");
```

Hope this helps !!!